# Need to apply all patches for TFS 2018 Update 3.2?

Tags: team-foundation-server

I see 16 patches on the TFS 2018 Update 3.2  page:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/tfs2018-update3#img-srcmedianews_iconsvg-altrelease-notes-icon-release-date-february-5-2019

I am confused if I need to apply each patch. Or does the latest patch include all others?

Are the security patches included in the Windows Update?

Comment: Updates to Microsoft products are cumulative.  You will want to download the update by itself to verify the update has been installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was raised in the 2020
[July patches for Azure DevOps Server and Team Foundation Server](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/july-patches-for-azure-devops-server-and-team-foundation-server/):

> **Q:** Is the “Azure DevOps Server 2019 Update 1.1 Patch 4 Release Date: July 14, 2020” update cumulative? Do I need to install patches
> 1, 2, and 3 first, or can I just install patch 4?
>
> **A:** updates are cumulative. You don’t need to install patches 1-3 first.